# How to "reserve" a file name or best way to make sure a file name will be available

Tags: .net, winforms, io

I need to call a method that will create a file and throw an exception if the file already exists. This might sound paranoiac but I think it would make lots of sense to have a method such as `string CreateTempFileNameAndReserveForThisProcess()`.

What is the closest thing I could get to this?

What I'm currently using is:

```
string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.Delete(tempFileName);
// Call the function that requires the file not to exist.
```

Comment: if (File.Exists(path)) ?

Comment: You basically require a method that generates a unique name like GetTempFileName() but not creates it, right? Given a uniquely generated string, would this solve your problem?

Comment: @Mr. I guess I can do that. I heard that's not the most reliable method though.

Comment: @J. Tihon: Yes, as long as I'm sure no other app (or perhaps another instance of my own app) will generate a file with the same name right after I generate the string.

Comment: the @Yiğit Yener comment, about the microsoft documentation says "The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if no unique temporary file name is available. To resolve this error, delete all unneeded temporary files." I used something like this to delete the temporary files,DirectoryInfo dirDownload = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                foreach (FileInfo file in dirDownload.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (file.CreationTime <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                    {
                        file.Delete();
                    }
                }

Comment: Why have this question been closed? Did you actually read it? The linked question asks how to make sure a file name doesn't have invalid characters. This question asks how to make sure the file name doesn't exist. Take a look at the accepted answers to each question and you'll see how they don't answer the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx

If you want to guarantee a unique file for each process/thread etc. you can just go create a file with the name `Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".tmp"`

Comment: That's what I'm using (see my edit). But the function I'm calling requires the file NOT to exist.

Comment: Why not use a Guid for the new file name then?

Comment: @jsoldi Yiğit is right-- that's probably the closest you can get to what you want.